# My div class is not applying to my div from another file

Tags: html, css

I have an HTML page for my code and a CSS page for all my classes/styling, but my div class is not applying to my div code.

It's weird because all of my other div classes are fine, but it's just this one.

My code is simple:

```
<div class="box">
</div>
```

And my class is also fairly simple:

```
.box {
    border-right: 10px solid black;
    border-left: 10px solid black;
    border-top: 10px solid black;
    border-bottom: 10px solid black;
}
```

It is probably a simple rookie mistake as I am new to this, but as I said, all the other classes work fine and they are the same as this.

Also, I tried putting the class in the HTML file itself, in [style], and it worked perfectly. I just wanted to know why it wasn't working when it was in another file when everything else was.

Comment: Do you use Developer Console of the browser? You can control the element class or styles on the developer console to do debug or something like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, after a bit more googling, I discovered it was as simple as doing shift + f5 to do a complete cache refresh. Turns out, if you have a completely separate file for all your CSS classes, it doesn't update the cache automatically.

Answer (score 1):

You must specify the width and height of the div. Because of that, it isn't showing the borders. Or, you can put some content inside your div, and after that, it will show the borders.

And a little advice: you don't have to type style for all border sides especially. You can just say: border: 10px solid black; and it will be applied to all sides of the box.

Comment: If that's true then why... _"Also, I tried putting the class in the HTML file itself, in , and it worked perfectly."_

Comment: As j08691 says - this does not help. I tried this, and it did nothing, but when it was in the same file as the HTML, it worked fine - even without any content in it or specifying the width/height. Either way, thank you for the extra advice.

Comment: update - it was as simple as doing shift + f5 to do a complete cache refresh. Turns out, if you have a completely separate file for all your CSS classes, it doesn't update the cache.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add some content to your div, or give a height to your div. If not, you will not be able to see your div and the border styles that you added.

In addition, you can make your code more efficient since all 4 border sides are the same styles. You can just use the following styling:

.box {
border: solid 10px black
}

Comment: If that's true then why... _"Also, I tried putting the class in the HTML file itself, in , and it worked perfectly."_